# Can I use Visual Studio with Unity?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I've been checking out [Unity](http://unity3d.com/) and it looks quite interesting.

In particular after reading you can use C# as the scripting language, I am left wondering if there is some sort of Visual Studio integration to leverage IntelliSense and all that jazz built into VS.

Comment: here's some recent documentation from the Unity site: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/VisualStudioIntegration.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Unity has a wiki page](http://www.unifycommunity.com/wiki/index.php?title=Setting_up_Visual_Studio_for_Unity) explaining how to do this. It seems that the latest version of Unity should already allow you to create a Visual Studio project (if you're running Windows). However, it [seems only VS 2008](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/VisualStudioIntegration.html) is supported natively. You can follow [this workaround](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/62200-Visual-Studio-2010-issue) to get it to work with VS2010 (except VS2010 Express Edition) to some degree.

Comment: +1 thanks for this - do you know if you can use the .NET libraries in such a visual studio project?

Comment: @JohnIdol - Unity is based on `Mono`, so it should support most libraries that `Mono` supports. There's a good post here on the differences: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/13247/how-does-c-in-unity-compare-with-using-regular-c-n.html

Answer (score 3):

Unity exports a VS 2008 project. I built a VS 2010 exporter so you can avoid fighting with the upgrade wizard. http://u3d.as/2gR

Answer (score 3):

You can check UnityVS from SyntaxTree. With this extension you can code & debug Unity 3D games using VisualStudio

http://unityvs.com/

[image: Debugging Unity in Visual Studio with UnityVS]

*Disclaimer: both Sébastien and I are working on UnityVS*

Comment: I looked on your website... do you have an ETA for trial runs?  Also does it allow remote debugging of Android?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft have now acquired UnityVS company SyntaxTree, and are offering UnityVS for free for Visual Studio 2010-2013 Professional or higher.

You can [download it here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/07/29/visual-studio-tools-for-unity-1-9.aspx), or get it from the Visual Studio Extensions Gallery.

Answer (score 0):

As of Unity 5.2, Visual Studio Tools are supported by Microsoft for Unity on Windows. [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn940025.aspx)

For OS X, Visual Studio Code can be used directly with Unity. [Source](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/runtimes/unity)